# Not wait for the parent @GraphQLContext resolver to resolve

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java, graphql-spqr

Is it possible to not have to wait for the parent `@GraphQLContext` resolver to fully resolve before executing the child-resolvers?

By looking at the source code I figured this might be possible by leveraging futures, something like so:

```
@GraphQLQuery
public Future<User> user() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(...);
}

@GraphQLQuery
public TwitterProfile twitterProfile(@GraphQLContext Future<User> user) {
    ...
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can compose an async chain using `CompletionStage` (of which a `CompletableFuture` is a subtype). Simple `Future` isn't enough as it doesn't allow composition. This is a feature of graphql-java itself, not SPQR specifically.

```
@GraphQLQuery
public CompletableFuture<User> user() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(...);
}

@GraphQLQuery
public TwitterProfile twitterProfile(@GraphQLContext User user) {
    ...
}
```

Note that the threading and concurrency is still fully under your control. This just lets you compose async resolvers as appropriate, but you need to actually start a thread that will complete the promise yourself (e.g. via `supplyAsync`). This also means fields on the same level can be resolved concurrently.

That said, the [GraphQL spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Executing-Selection-Sets) mandates the parent field is resolved before the children:

> the *object value* being evaluated and the object type *need to be known*

(emphasis mine). This is mostly because the result of the parent query is needed for the children to resolve, not some special constraint.
If you have a field that is truly independent of its parent, I'd go as far as to argue it should not have a parent in the first place.